# An adjective for "in the wrong register"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm trying to fix this sentence:

> There's a lot of poor word and phrase choice that is either redundant,
>   in  the wrong register, or flatly ungrammatical.

The problem is that the compound "either redundant, in the wrong register, or flatly ungrammatical" isn't parallel because the prep. phrase "in the wrong register" is being joined with two simple adjectives.

Is there a plain adjective that means "in the wrong register" to replace it with?

Comment: Inapt or inappropriate?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with *..choice that **is** .. 1) redundant,  2) in the wrong register, 3) flatly ungrammatical.*    Seems parallel to me.

Comment: It is parallel. If you want to replace "in the wrong register" with a simpler phrase, you could say "either redundant, too shrill, or flatly ungrammatical," for example.

Comment: @surlawda I thought that a PP would have to be joined with other PP for the compound to be parallel.

Comment: Not at all. If the prepositional phrase functions as an adjective, which it does in this case, it may then be included on a list of any number of adjectives, whether they are single words or longer phrases. Some prepositional phrases act as adverbs (for example, "he went there in a car," in which "in a car" explains how he traveled), but here the phrase clearly is descriptive: redundant, in the wrong register, and flatly ungrammatical are three qualities that characterize the word choice.

Comment: I should add that many will object to your use of the word "either," which, according to prescriptivists, should be used only when two items are involved. This word could be dropped from your sentence without affecting the meaning, but it is commonly used as you have used it here, and many others believe that is OK. Also, "poor" might itself be considered redundant, because word choice that is redundant, in the wrong register, or flatly ungrammatical is, by definition, poor.

Comment: 'Either' with multiple 'ors' is fine with me (mind, I do say 'eether' not 'eye-ther').

Comment: Leave it as it is. If you ***can*** make things parallel ***easily,*** you should. But often you can't. Consider the famous *"Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you"*. That's not parallel.

Comment: (1) I can do calculations manually or with a computer. I have traveled within my home country and overseas. (OK, I guess these are adverbs rather than adjectives, but I think the principle is the same.) Are you troubled by the lack of parallelism in these sentences? (2) Am I the only person who has a problem with “There’s a lot of” used with a *singular* count noun? (There’s a lot of book in the library.) Or is “choice” considered to be a mass noun (like “usage”)?

Answer (score 1):

There is such an adjective:

> misregistered, adj.
>   ....
>   Wrongly or imperfectly registered ....

["misregistered, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/254881?redirectedFrom=misregistered (accessed November 24, 2015).]

The word has some drawbacks for your use: (1) in linguistics, 'register' is used imprecisely to start, so use of 'misregistered' in linguistics tends to emphasize that original defect; (2) 'misregistered' is commonly and appropriately applied to imperfectly aligned printing, a use where the term is precise rather than vague and ill-defined or multiply defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the adjective **malapropos**

> Definition: in an inappropriate or inopportune way; awkward or improper.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because of some music background, I think first of *dissonant*, but that leads down the synonym path to:

> [***incongruous***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incongruous) -
>
> out of keeping or place; inappropriate; unbecoming

There's also *tone-deaf* if you want to be particularly judgemental about how *discordant* the phrasing is.  *Incongrous* is a rather mild criticism.